# JavaScript Cookie flashes hidden DIV for split second

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, lightbox, hidden

I have a pop-up lightbox on my page, I also have a cookie using JavaScript to only show that pop-up lightbox every 15 days.

The code does what I want it to do, except if I keep refreshing the page to check the cookie, my pop-up lightbox flashes on the screen for a split second then goes away.

How do I prevent this?

Test Page - http://mymsaa.org/videos/test-lightbox/

My test page does have A LOT of scripts on it for plugins and my WordPress theme so I can't post the WHOLE code.

The Javascript...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}
return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

function setTheDivStyle() {
if(!readCookie('wroteIt')) {
// if cookie not found display the div and create the cookie
document.getElementById("theLink").style.display="block";
createCookie('wroteIt', 'wroteIt', 1);  // 1 day = 24 hours persistence
}
else {
// if cookie found hide the div
document.getElementById("theLink").style.display="none";
}
}
</script>
```

My pop-up lightbox...

```
<div id = "theLink" style="display:block"><!--LIGHTBOX-->      

<div class="ezmodal" ezmodal-autoopen="true">
<div class="ezmodal-container">

<!--IFRAME FORM-->                                            
<div id='subscribe_popup' style='overflow: hidden; overflow-y:hidden;'>
<div style="padding: 10px;">

<iframe src="http://mymsaa.org/wp-content/themes/dw-focus/video_register/iframe/iframe.php" border="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="pop"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<!--IFRAME FORM--> 

<div class="ezmodal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn1" data-dismiss="ezmodal">X</button>
</div>

</div>
</div>

<!--LIGHTBOX--></div>
```

My BODY tag...

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?> onload = "setTheDivStyle()">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just hide it from the start by giving the `div` a `display:none` style in the original HTML:

```
<div id = "theLink" style="display:none"><!--LIGHTBOX-->
```

Then the `onload` event handler you have will show it if necessary. That way it never shows while the page is loading but the event was not yet triggered.

Comment: How do I hide it from the start?

Comment: Like I mentioned: in the HTML code change the `style` attribute to mention `display:none`.